# Compilation error when using Scaldi

Tags: scala, dependency-injection, scaldi

I am following the steps mentioned in [Scaldi documentaiton](http://scaldi.org/learn/#inject-bindings). Following is my code.

```
class Game(players: List[Player], currentPlayer: Player,
           board: Board, active: Boolean, gamePersistor: GamePersistor) extends Injectable {

  def this(players: List[Player], currentPlayer: Player,
           board: Board, active: Boolean)(implicit inj: Injector) {
    this(players, currentPlayer, board, active, inject[GamePersistor])
  }
}
```

I get the following compilation error.

```
Error:(11, 49) not found: value inject
    this(players, currentPlayer, board, active, inject[GamePersistor])
                                                ^
```

Can someone help me solve this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured out from the documentation

All forms of inject expect and implicit instance of Injector to be in scope. If

> you are injecting in the module definition, then it already provides
>   one for you. If you are injecting in you own classes, then the best
>   approach would be to provide the implicit injector instance as a
>   constructor argument, as shown in the example above.

So the code should be

```
class Game(players: List[Player], currentPlayer: Player,
           board: Board, active: Boolean, gamePersistor: GamePersistor)(implicit inj:Injector) extends Injectable {

  def this(players: List[Player], currentPlayer: Player,
           board: Board, active: Boolean)(implicit inj: Injector) {
    this(players, currentPlayer, board, active, inject[GamePersistor])
  }
}
```